# Stop vibration fedback

Tags: vibration

How can I stop my HTC m8 from vibration at the start and end of call? I turned off all vibration notifications but still I can't stop my phone from vibrating at the start and end of calls.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Settings application on your device and Navigate to `Sound` and uncheck the option labelled `Vibrate` with a description of `Vibration feedback for calls`.